# Technique to draw relative velocities vectors and diagrams

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

How do you start drawing a diagram in a problem with relative velocities? I always see my coursemates and my lecturer drawing them in a second, as soon as they read the text, I asked them how they did it, they just couldn't explain cause it just comes naturally. But to me it's very hard to figure out how to actually draw them as we are talking about different frames.

For example consider this problem 
[image: river]
 Now I draw this after a while, where $V_{bo}$ is the velocity of the boat wrt the ocean, $V_{og}$ is the velocity of the ocean wrt the ground, and  $V_{bg}$ is the velocity of the boat wrt to the ground. But the diagram, it is quite random really, because I could have easily put the arrows in another order, but with the same direction! So for example I could have put the head of $V_{og}$ where $V_{bo}$ starts or other changes.
[image]

> How do I decide how to put the arrows? In "putting the arrows" I mean, how do I know I have to put $V_{og}$ starting point as the same of $V_{bo}$ and not put the head of the first, where the second starts? And what about where the second has its head?

Is it related to the formula $$V_{ab} = V_{ac} + V_{cb}$$ ? and if so how? I really struggle everytime to draw these diagrams and it takes me more than half an hour every time..

**EDIT**
To show what I mean here's my drawing:
[image: triangles]

As you can see it works fine most of the times. But if I follow the advice of connecting the heads or the tails of the two absolute velocities, I can get a different vector, as shown in the last two triangles of column 1, but you could get the same on the left side as well. Also, we don't know which of those triangle would be correct, or do we?

Comment: See my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4182031/476357) for a simple method.

Answer (score 1):

The velocity of the boat relative to the ocean is the velocity of the boat minus the velocity of the ocean. The last two terms are what you are referring to as relative to the ground, or absolute velocities.

The vectors oney the triangular law of vector addition.

Draw a triangle so that the arrow heads of the two absolute velocities either converge at one point or both head away from one point.

The third side of the triangle is the relative velocity.

Follow the arrows to indicate the correct direction of the relative velocity.

Comment: in your third paragraph "Draw a triangle so that..", how do I know whether they converge or diverge at one point? Like is my diagram correct? And if so, how do we know it is

Comment: You can draw two equally valid triangles. Either the absolute velocities point towards one point or they point both away from one point. In each case the third side is the relative velocity. I drew a picture but I don't seem to be able to upload the image - sorry.

Comment: okay that works of course, but there are other "degrees of freedom". In my diagram $V_{bg}$ and $V_{og}$ are the absolute velocities. From the text I know $V_{og}$ is vertical and pointing downwards. However I know nothing about $V_{bg}$. How do I decide at what angle they meet? For example in my photo I started from drawing $V_{og}$, then $V_{bo}$ with the angle $\phi$ with the vertical axis. But I could have never started from the two absolute velocities! Also, I have no way to check that my final diagram is correct, indeed I have no idea if mine is

Comment: Your diagram is not correct. The $v_{bo}$ and the $v_{bg}$ should be swapped over. The angles are unknown so it doesn't matter.

Comment: so now there's a problem with reality. If we have a current against us, in order to reach the same point, we have to have a bigger component in the same direction of the flow (so vertical), keeping the trasversal component the same (horizontal). And indeed in the diagram $v_{bg}$ has same horizontal component of $V_{bo}$ but bigger vertical component! How do you know they should be swapped over? Sorry I really struggle with this

Comment: your technique of the head or the same starting point clearly doesn't work. Indeed if say the one with the same stating point is the correct diagram, then if I redo the diagram, but making a vector with the head in the same point of the first, I'll get a vector which is indeed the third vector in the previous diagram

Comment: Keep the same triangle with the arrows as thet are and just relabel the boat velocities. Just swap them over and your diagram will be correct!

Comment: thank you for that! But I would like to learn HOW. Not every time have to look at the answer or ask someone. There is an ambiguity in the diagrams. As I said, take a triangle made of vectors. of course you can take one of the vector and shift it. But since you have an unknown here, you are shifting also the length of the vector when you move it!

Comment: I've added an edit with an image

Comment: The two diagrams in column one are equivalent and correct. A is the velocity of the ocean. B is the velocity of the boat. C os the velocity of the boat relative to the ocean.

Comment: okay, but how do you know those are the correct ones? And why are the others wrong?

Comment: Because those are the only ones which accurately reflect the data in the question and satisfy the relative velocity equation/definition (see my post)