# Two rules for relative velocity triangles (relative velocity diagrams)

Tags: vectors

*Note: This question talks about velocities, however it could be for any vector (i.e. this question does not involve any physics)*

---

I have come up with two simple rules when drawing a relative velocity triangle.

A relative velocity triangle is a diagram showing the vectors $V_A$, $V_B$ and $V_{AB}$, where $V_{AB}$ is the relative velocity between $A$ and $B$ i.e. $V_A - V_B$.

Two rules I have come up with are:

- $V_{AB}$ always points from $A$ to $B$ (i.e. from the backside of the arrow $V_A$ to the backside of the arrow $V_B$).
- $V_A$ and $V_B$ point into each other (i.e. their arrowheads touch).

You can see these rules in action in the following example diagram:

[image]

My question is: Are these rules always correct?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2098161/476357) answers my question -- the rules do seem to be correct.

There are two possible triangles for each relative velocity diagram, and so $V_A$ and $V_B$ could be "diverging" instead of "converging" as well. When it's diverging, the relative velocity vector is instead drawn from $B$ to $A$.

---

> [image]